# Сложные запросы в hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Что более предпочтительно с точки зрения ресурсоемкости, если нужна выборка из базы со сложными связами (join): один сложный sql-запрос или несколько простых запросов с обработкой в java? Какие есть способы проверить это на практике и сравнить результаты?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один сложный лучше. Во-первых, оптимизатор построит план выполнения с учётом структуры данных, наличия индексов и статистики таблиц, во-вторых, не нужно гонять по сети на клиента тонны лишних (и как правило ненужных) промежуточных данных.